# How to apply-templates to all templates except a spefic one

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In the code bellow I'm applying all the templates to the element chapter (in the end of the code) but I would like to know how it is possible to apply all the templates to this element except a spefic one. In this case it's the element title because I'm already selecting it in the line before and it appears repeated in the html file. Someone?

```
<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <h3>
       <a name="{@id}"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a>
    </h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
Title<br>
Text.
```

Comment: What to do using XPath 1.0?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A plain `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is equivalent to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />`, i.e. all child nodes.  You can exclude certain nodes by using the XPath 2.0 [`except` operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#combining_seq), e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() except title" />
```

This would select all child nodes *except* those that are elements with the name `title`.  If you are only interested in child *elements* (not text nodes etc.) then you could use `* except title` instead.

The `except` operator essentially implements set difference - you're not limited to simple element names on the right, you can use any expression that returns a sequence of nodes, e.g.

```
node() except (title | div[@class = 'heading'])
```

`X except Y` selects all nodes that are in the sequence selected by `X` *and not also in* the sequence selected by `Y`